# How to make website accessible only afte password authorized

Tags: php, apache, web

I have a simple website which is write in static html, but I only want to share it in my small group, so I'd like to set a **password**, people can only  view its content after password authorized.

I do not want to change my old files because there is too much to do. I have a simple idea that I just put a single `index.php` file in the web_root, than if authorized, anything like `index.php/foo/bar.html` be redirect to the `foo/bar.html` in another directory which is outsize the apache server root, that means inaccessible except `index.php` redirect.

So, is it possible? How about the detail way? I am not very good at web so this question may be a little stupied, sorry for it.

Comment: Use basic auth:  https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PasswordBasicAuth

Comment: @Stuart tried and successed, very nice solution.